# Spring boot project throws *$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB is not an @AspectJ aspect when maven build is running tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, aspectj

I have a spring boot app using a component (jar) that got some annotations and an aspectj advice (.aj). Both are maven projects and the component (jar) build runs all fine, but with the spring app I'm not been able to build it successfully.

Basically my aspect is used to log some info. It looks for a trigger annotation (@GetMapping in this case) and when the thread finishes it's processing, some collected data will be displayed. For that, my spring app may have some methods annotated with @Loggable to determine which ones will have their data collected or not.

Please notice that I need more than Spring AOP offers and just for example I simplified the things to reproduce my error.

The classes are apparently woven successfully, but when maven is running tests (app starting) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.673 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.rct.aspectj.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAspectResource' defined in file [C:\workspace\myaspectj-app\target\test-classes\com\rct\aspectj\myaspectjapp\resource\MyAspectResource.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class 'com.rct.aspectj.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12a7b207' is not an @AspectJ aspect
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class 'com.rct.aspectj.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12a7b207' is not an @AspectJ aspect
```

Here are my spring app pom and some classes snippets. Example code can be found here: https://github.com/rctbatista/myaspectj-project

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/aspect")
public class MyAspectResource {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @GetMapping(path = "/sayhello/{name}") //@GetMapping annotation that triggers my aspect
    public ResponseEntity<String> teste(@PathVariable String name){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.sayHello(name));
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    @Loggable
    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        try {
            long timeToSleep = new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1000;
            Thread.sleep(timeToSleep);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

Spring app POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rct.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>myaspectj-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myaspectj-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rct.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>myaspectj-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- updagrading the aspectjtools version for aspectj-maven-plugin -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <weaveDirectories>
                        <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes
                        </weaveDirectory>
                    </weaveDirectories>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.rct.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myaspectj-lib</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>weaving-classes</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

More details of the error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.rct.aspectj:myaspectj-app >--------------------
[INFO] Building myaspectj-app 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:compile (weaving-classes) @ myaspectj-app ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity c.r.a.myaspectjapp.resource.MyAspectResource.teste(java.lang.String))' in Type 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.resource.MyAspectResource' (MyAspectResource.java:22) advised by before advice from 'c.r.a.core.aspect.LoggableAspect' (myaspectj-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!LoggableAspect.class:20(from LoggableAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity c.r.a.myaspectjapp.resource.MyAspectResource.teste(java.lang.String))' in Type 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.resource.MyAspectResource' (MyAspectResource.java:22) advised by afterReturning advice from 'c.r.a.core.aspect.LoggableAspect' (myaspectj-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!LoggableAspect.class:26(from LoggableAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(java.lang.String c.r.a.myaspectjapp.service.SomeServiceImpl.sayHello(java.lang.String))' in Type 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.service.SomeServiceImpl' (SomeServiceImpl.java:14) advised by around advice from 'c.r.a.core.aspect.LoggableAspect' (myaspectj-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!LoggableAspect.class:36(from LoggableAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:test-compile (weaving-classes) @ myaspectj-app ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(java.lang.String c.r.a.myaspectjapp.service.SomeServiceImpl.sayHello(java.lang.String))' in Type 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.service.SomeServiceImpl' (SomeServiceImpl.java:14) advised by around advice from 'c.r.a.core.aspect.LoggableAspect' (myaspectj-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!LoggableAspect.class:36(from LoggableAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity c.r.a.myaspectjapp.resource.MyAspectResource.teste(java.lang.String))' in Type 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.resource.MyAspectResource' (MyAspectResource.java:22) advised by before advice from 'c.r.a.core.aspect.LoggableAspect' (myaspectj-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!LoggableAspect.class:20(from LoggableAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity c.r.a.myaspectjapp.resource.MyAspectResource.teste(java.lang.String))' in Type 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.resource.MyAspectResource' (MyAspectResource.java:22) advised by afterReturning advice from 'c.r.a.core.aspect.LoggableAspect' (myaspectj-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!LoggableAspect.class:26(from LoggableAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] 
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ myaspectj-app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests
18:02:54.568 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
18:02:54.587 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
18:02:54.638 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
18:02:54.668 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
18:02:54.676 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/rct/aspectj/myaspectjapp/MyaspectjAppApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
18:02:54.695 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/rct/aspectj/myaspectjapp/MyaspectjAppApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
18:02:54.702 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
18:02:54.705 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests]: MyaspectjAppApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
18:02:54.814 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests]
18:02:54.954 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\workspace\myaspectj-app\target\test-classes\com\rct\aspectj\myaspectjapp\MyaspectjAppApplication.class]
18:02:54.962 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\workspace\myaspectj-app\target\classes\com\rct\aspectj\myaspectjapp\MyaspectjAppApplication.class]
18:02:54.974 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication for test class c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests
18:02:55.155 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests]: using defaults.
18:02:55.156 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
18:02:55.192 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeSource]
18:02:55.195 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttribute]
18:02:55.195 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4310d43, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@54a7079e, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@26e356f0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@47d9a273, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@4b8ee4de, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@27f981c6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@1b11171f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@1151e434, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@2dc54ad4, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@4659191b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@55634720, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@4b0d79fc]
18:02:55.222 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@273e7444 testClass = MyaspectjAppApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7db12bb6 testClass = MyaspectjAppApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@76908cc0, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@49b0b76, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@e056f20, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6ca8564a, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
18:02:55.294 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-06-15 18:02:55.848  INFO 11328 --- [           main] c.r.a.m.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests     : Starting MyaspectjAppApplicationTests on d4253s000n186 with PID 11328 (started by F929362 in C:\workspace\myaspectj-app)
2020-06-15 18:02:55.852  INFO 11328 --- [           main] c.r.a.m.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-15 18:02:56.908  WARN 11328 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAspectResource' defined in file [C:\workspace\myaspectj-app\target\test-classes\com\rct\aspectj\myaspectjapp\resource\MyAspectResource.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12a7b207' is not an @AspectJ aspect
2020-06-15 18:02:56.937  INFO 11328 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-15 18:02:56.947 ERROR 11328 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAspectResource' defined in file [C:\workspace\myaspectj-app\target\test-classes\com\rct\aspectj\myaspectjapp\resource\MyAspectResource.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12a7b207' is not an @AspectJ aspect
    ...

2020-06-15 18:02:56.953 ERROR 11328 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4310d43] to prepare test instance [c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests@437ebf59]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) [spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAspectResource' defined in file [C:\workspace\myaspectj-app\target\test-classes\com\rct\aspectj\myaspectjapp\resource\MyAspectResource.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12a7b207' is not an @AspectJ aspect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12a7b207' is not an @AspectJ aspect
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AspectMetadata.<init>(AspectMetadata.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:106) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 79 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.673 s <<< FAILURE! - in c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAspectResource' defined in file [C:\workspace\myaspectj-app\target\test-classes\com\rct\aspectj\myaspectjapp\resource\MyAspectResource.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12a7b207' is not an @AspectJ aspect
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class 'c.r.a.myaspectjapp.MyaspectjAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12a7b207' is not an @AspectJ aspect

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   MyaspectjAppApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Applic...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.149 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-15T18:02:57-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project myaspectj-app: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\workspace\myaspectj-app\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Anybody seeing anything wrong or missing that might be the cause of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this adding **spring.aop.auto=false** on your application.properties

I found this at
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/aop-aspectj/